# I set a script to start at boot with kde startup and now if I log into my main account it locks after I click anything to delete it

Tags: scripts, kde, startup, crash, konsole

I'm new to Linux and I was trying to set a script to adjust my mouse acceleration on startup but when I set the script path on kde startup I didn't adjust the text file to anything special I just left it as such and now if I log into my main account it will crash whenever I click anything trying to launch the text editor. I know the name of the file and where it is but not how to get to it from the terminal before boot to delete it and maybe fix the issue. I'm logged in as a guest on my computer trying to find a solution. If anyone knows a better solution please help!

Answer (score 0):

From the guest session, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, log into your main account, delete the file, log out, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>, log back in.

Done!